# View detailed information when the user click on a map

Tags: javascript, css, html, dhtml

I have been taking over responsibility for a site for a golf club when the person who made the page no longer has time to manage it. The most urgent now is to fix a flash animation that presents information about the holes that simply don't work. I will do it in JavaScript, but it was long ago I did something like that, and it's rush to fix it. So I ask for help here.

**requirements:**

1. A map of the entire golf course must be displayed
2. It should be possible to click on the various holes on the map
3. When the user click on a hole on the map, a detailed picture of the hole is shown together with description of the hole and advertising for the sponsor of the hole
4. (Optional) Advertising must be flying in place with an animation so that the user noticing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought i was in the google maps section for some reason. Here's my revised answer

Fastest way:

Create an image map using http://www.maschek.hu/imagemap/imgmap. Instead of loading a URL when the area is clicked load an overlay using [thickbox](http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/) or something similar

---

Original answer:

If you need it done quickly i would recommend placing a polygon over each hole and attaching a click handler to the polygon to show the other info

Here's a polygon creator: http://www.the-di-lab.com/polygon/

Google Maps polygon documentation http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#Polygons

I do a lot of google mapping, so if you need some help email me.

Comment: i am not sure about the OP, but this surely is very helpful for me. +1 Galen for such a nice answer. :)

Comment: Can I use this with a my own map or is it locked to the rough map from google?

Comment: i thought i was in the google maps section or some reason. ill update my answer